# Is there any concept similar to unique factorization that applies to exponential operators?

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, prime-factorization, hyperoperation

We can talk about prime numbers over multiplication but is there any similar concept that applies to exponential operators or other hyperpowers like tetration? Can we use what we know about UFDs to say anything about exponential operators and exponential "primes?" Or does the process of defining exponentiation strip the qualities that allow unique factorization?

Comment: Probably the problem is that exponentiation is not always commutative: $a^b\neq b^a$.

Comment: Exponentiation isn't even associative. That isn't a problem with UFDs necessarily, as there are non-commutative UFDs like Hurwitz quaternions and non-associative UFD's like cayley integers described by Smith and Conway over the octonions.